# How to perform a similar operation as AffineTransformOp.filter on Android?

Tags: android

`public final BufferedImage filter(BufferedImage src, BufferedImage dst)`

> > Transforms the source `BufferedImage` and stores the results 
> >     in the destination `BufferedImage`.
> >     If the color models for the two images do not match, a color
> >     conversion into the destination color model is performed.
> >     If the destination image is `null`, a `BufferedImage` is created with the source 
> >     `ColorModel`.
> >     The coordinates of the rectangle returned by 
> >     `getBounds2D(BufferedImage)` are not necessarily the same as the coordinates of the 
> >     `BufferedImage` returned by this method. If the upper-left corner coordinates
> >     of the rectangle are negative then this part of the rectangle is not drawn. If the
> >     upper-left corner coordinates of the  rectangle are positive then the filtered image is
> >     drawn at that position in the destination `BufferedImage`.

I had the following code on Java 1.6:

```
//Make image always std_height tall
double scaleAmount = (double) std_height / (double) characterImage.getHeight();
AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
tx.scale(scaleAmount, scaleAmount);
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
characterImage = op.filter(characterImage, null);
```

In Android, i'm using Matrix instead of AffineTransform:

```
//Make image always std_width wide
float scaleAmount = (float) std_width / (float) characterImage.getWidth();
//AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
//tx.scale(scaleAmount, scaleAmount);
Matrix mx = new Matrix();
mx.setScale(scaleAmount, scaleAmount);
//AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR); //Can't use this on Android
//characterImage = op.filter(characterImage, null); //Can't use this on Android
```

My problem is with the last two commented lines. Can i do something like it on Android? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(scaleAmount, scaleAmount);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(original, 0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), m, true);
```

(***Note***: BTW, Oracle JavaSE `AffineTransformOp#filter` has a bug when the output `BufferedImage` is null, it creates a `BufferedImage` but with default colorspace, not the one of the input BufferedImage.)